# PowerShell date time conversion issue

Tags: powershell

When I run the below two PowerShell statements, I expect them to return the same result, but in fact they return different results:

```
New-TimeSpan $(Get-Date) $(Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2016)
New-TimeSpan $(Get-Date) $(Get-Date "2016-12-31")
```

The results are:

```
Days              : 751
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 1
Ticks             : 648864000010001
TotalDays         : 751.000000011575
TotalHours        : 18024.0000002778
TotalMinutes      : 1081440.00001667
TotalSeconds      : 64886400.0010001
TotalMilliseconds : 64886400001.0001

Days              : 750
Hours             : 6
Minutes           : 50
Seconds           : 13
Milliseconds      : 67
Ticks             : 648246130673175
TotalDays         : 750.284873464323
TotalHours        : 18006.8369631437
TotalMinutes      : 1080410.21778863
TotalSeconds      : 64824613.0673175
TotalMilliseconds : 64824613067.3175
```

What's going on?

Comment: It seems that `(Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2016)` is also taking the current time. whereas the other is set to midnight. Must be related to use using the 2 different parameter sets.

Comment: Have you tried breaking this down into pieces?  e.g. calling `Get-Date` and storing the value and using that value in constructing the new `TimeSpan`?

Comment: In addition to the issue @Matt points out ... by calling `Get-Date` (with no parameters) twice, you're using (slightly) different values, at least in theory.

Comment: @David Yes Get-Date returns the current date and time each time it is called, but the difference would be on the order of milliseconds not 17+ hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is in the different parameter sets you are using. Referring to [the TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) article. There are two different parameter sets: `net` and `uformat`

- `Get-Date "2016-12-31"` is is being detected as `net`
- `(Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2016)` is being detected as `uformat`

In the latter, since you are not specifying the time components, it is defaulting them to the current time. Looking at the documentation for `-Hour`

```
-Hour<Int32>
Specifies the hour that is displayed. Enter a value from 1 to 23. The default is the current hour.
```

When the string "2016-12-31" is cast to a datetime midnight, it is used in the absence of a value. In the other case no time is specified, so it is using the current time in its place.

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> (Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2016)

Saturday, December 31, 2016 5:14:32 PM


PS C:\Users\Cameron> $(Get-Date "2016-12-31")

Saturday, December 31, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

I might be slightly wrong on the terms or cause, but I have to be close. Even when specifying hour for example the other time values still need to come from somewhere. The time when the code was run was 5:24 pm EST.

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> (Get-Date -month 12 -day 31 -year 2016 -Hour 12)

Saturday, December 31, 2016 12:24:43 PM
```